# Camera pivoting onto 3D Cursor rather than selected object

Tags: 3d-view, camera, 3d-cursor

Through the viewport, by pressing the <kbd>NumpadPeriod</kbd> (the decimal point on the numpad), the camera focuses on the *3D Cursor*, rather than the vertices I have selected, how do I fix this issue?

*I am using Blender v2.79.*

Comment: I can't reprduce your problem. Could remove all unneeded item from your file and upload a condensed version of it to [blend-exchange](www.blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.org)? Then edit your question and include a link to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem by unselecting the "Lock the Cursor" function on the properties panel under "Views". I've also found that the function also effect's your camera when your rotating the view (middle mouse held down and moving the mouse), so it pivots around the 3D Cursor rather then just rotating the camera.